# Received http status code 302 from server while fetching consensus directory

Tags: configuration, log, consensus

Running a tor relay on `Centos 7`, version `0.3.5.8`.

Looking at the `notices.log`, I've noticed this warning for the first time in a week:

`[warn] Received http status code 302 ("Found") from server '<Server IP>' while fetching consensus directory.`

After some searching, other users have seen the same warning with http code 404 (not found), however I'm receiving a 302 (found). I couldn't find anyone else reporting this kind of warning.

The way I understand it is that < Server IP > sent a http request (via tor) to my server, and my server replied with code 302. I'm not sure this is ok.

**Is this something I need to worry about? Do I need to perhaps check some of my settings?**

My torrc config looks something like this (comments stripped for brevity):

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
ORPort 9001
Address <my server ip>
Nickname <some name>
ContactInfo <some info>
DirPortFrontPage /<somepath>/tor-exit-notice.html
ExitRelay 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [suggested configuration for CentOS](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/guard/centosrhel/). As long as you aren't running an exit node, this should be all you need. You can also find help from fellow relay operators [here](https://community.torproject.org/relay/).

Comment: Understood. I take it you're saying that's nothing to worry about as I did review the info from the tor project website.

Comment: pretty much. I always keep an eye on https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html to make sure that the network doesn't see anything wrong with my relay that I should be concerned about.